# Probability of selecting a set of three numbers from S={1,2,3,..,20}

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Let S={1,2,3,...,20}. Find the probability of choosing a subset of three numbers from the set S so that no two consecutive numbers are selected in the set.
"I am getting problem in forming the required number of sets."

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. Please show us which concept you are having difficulty with.

Comment: My first instinct is to define the event $A_{i}$ as the event that both $i$ and $i+1$ are included in our set of three numbers selected.  We are looking for the complement of $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{19} A_i$ which can have its cardinality determined through inclusion-exclusion noting that the intersection of three events is always empty and the intersection of two events is nonempty iff the indexes are adjacent.

Comment: A different and probably easier technique to utilize would be instead of considering sets of the form $\{a,b,c\}$ where $a<b<c$, consider quadruples $(a-1,b-a-2,c-b-2,20-c)$ and note that the entries of such a quadruple add up to $15$.  You should be able to convince yourself that every entry in such a quadruple is a non-negative integer and that every such quadruple uniquely corresponds uniquely to such a three-element subset from your original question and vice versa, so it suffices to count these instead which can be done with stars-and-bars.

Answer (score 2):

To remove from unanswered queue:

Consider the related problem of counting how many quadruples $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ of non-negative integers exist such that $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=15$

Count the number of such possible quadruples using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Recognize that there is a bijection between the sets of non-negative integer quadruples adding to $15$ and the three-element subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots,20\}$ containing no consecutive numbers.

> Explicitly the bijection takes a set $\{a,b,c\}$ and maps it to $(a-1,b-a-2,c-b-2,20-c)$ in the one direction, or it takes a quadruple $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ and maps it to $\{(x_1+1),(x_2+x_1+3),(x_3+x_2+x_1+5)\}$ in the other direction.  You should conform that this truly is a bijection between the sets.

Now, this tells us how many three-element subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots,20\}$ have the property we want.  Taking the ratio then with the total number of three-element subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots,20\}$ will give us the probability that a uniformly randomly selected three-element subset will have the desired property.

> $\dfrac{\binom{18}{3}}{\binom{20}{3}}$

---

> In retrospect, after writing this answer I realize the bijection could also instead be formed with the three-element subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots,18\}$ instead.  Let $\{a,b,c\}$ be a three-element subset from $\{1,2,3,\dots,18\}$ with $a<b<c$.  Map this to $\{a,b+1,c+2\}$ which will be a three-element subset of $\{1,2,3,\dots,20\}$ with no consecutive numbers.

Comment: The retrospect is great! +1

Answer (score 2):

$\underline{Another\; approach}$

For any chosen subset of $3$, there will be $17$ left unchosen,  and the three chosen must have come from any $3$ of $18$ gaps (including ends) marked with an uparrow,

$\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\quad$thus $\dfrac{\binom{18}{3}}{\binom{20}{3}}$

Answer (score 1):

Count the total ways to select any three numbers from the set of twenty.

Count the ways to select a number, its immediate successor, and any other number *that is not the first number's immediate predecessor* (to avoid overcounting).   There will be two cases to consider: first select $1$ or first select from $\{2..19\}$

Subtract and divide as appropriate to get the probability.

---

Alternately:

Count ways to select any three numbers from $\{2..19\}$, so you can then subtract one from the least and add one to the greatest to ensure they are not consecutive *and* come from $\{1..20\}$.

Count the total ways to select any three numbers from the set of twenty.

Divide and answer.

Answer (score 1):

***Inclusion-Exclusion Principle:-***
Suppose $A_i$ denote the event that both the numbers $i,$ and $i+1$ ($i=1,2,...,19$) are included in the set.
$n(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{19} A_i)$ will denote the total number of cases where we can find at least two consecutive integers.

Here, $n(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{19} A_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{19}n(A_i)-\sum \sum_{i\ne j}n(A_i\cap A_j)$
[Terms like $n(A_i,A_j,A_k)$ and others vanishes]

Now, for  an instance if you choose $1,2$ then there are $18$ other choices. So, $n(A_i)=18$, $i=1,2,....19$

$n(A_i\cap A_j)$ just requires how many consecutive tuples like $(1,2,3),(2,3,4)$  you may have. Obviously this number is $18$
So,$n(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{19} A_i)=18\times 19 -18=324$

Required probability $=1-\frac{324}{\binom{20}{3}}=\frac{816}{\binom{20}{3}}$

Comment: Thanks to JMoravitz for providing the hint for this technique.